# Selenium rotate iOS device with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mobile-safari, appium

I have an issue that I cannot seem to resolve. I am writing an automated testing application in Java using `JUnit/Selenium` with `Appium` to test a website in the iOS simulator (`Mobile Safari`).

In this automated testing application I want to run some tests, rotate the device and run another set of tests. I've got everything working correctly except the rotation piece.

I found the following [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/appium-discuss/oQfobiLAXTY/) on how to rotate the iOS device in which someone suggested using the following Java code:

```
WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
        ((Rotatable)augmentedDriver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

However I am getting the following cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be 
cast to org.openqa.selenium.Rotatable
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue and know a fix/workaround? Maybe using Appium's JSON wire protocol?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I finally figured out the issue. Annoying that after hours of searching and trying different things it was a very simple solution.

All that is needed is the following Capability:

```
cap.setCapability("rotatable", true);
```

Then use the following code to rotate the device:

```
WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
((Rotatable)augmentedDriver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

YEAH! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Rotation is not implemented and this request is marked as "won't fix". Check [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2735).
As far as i know, this is because rotating screen is already implemented in Appium so yes, check the Appium API for solution. Alternatively you can try to execute javascript, something together with `target.setDeviceOrientation`, but I would go with the first one.

Comment: do you have any thoughts on the command for using the Appium API to rotate? I can't seem to find anything via Google. Thx!

Comment: Sorry, I really know a little of using the Appium API, because people in my country are too poor to have Apple devices : )